# How to sort terms of custom taxonomies created programmatic via Wordpress back-end?

Tags: wordpress, sorting, taxonomy

I have a problem with sorting terms of custom taxonomy. I need some way to sort them manually (not alphabetical or by date) via WP back-end. In future I need to show them in that order.

Would be gratefull for some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin Custom Taxonomy Sort (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-taxonomy-sort/) will be of great assistance to you. Install the plugin, visit your custom taxonomy page, and start inputting order values to control the order of your terms.